# MVC: Get jQuery Intellisense in T4 Templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, intellisense, t4

Is there any way to get jQuery Support / Intellisense in T4-Templates? In normal `js-Files`,

I can write

```
/// <reference path="/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2-vsdoc.js" />
```

But how to do it in `T4-Templates`?

***EDIT***

The reason why we want to do so: because we seperated our JavaScript in external js-Files. Doing so means that it is no longer possible to use c#-Code in our JavaScript to avoid magic strings. For example:

**Instead of writing:**

```
$j.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Edit'
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html'
        data: {},
        error: function() {
            DisplayMessage("Error while generating filter dialog");
        }
});
```

**we write:**

```
$j.ajax({
        url: '<#= ControllerViewNameProvider.FilterSettings.ControllerName #>/<#= ControllerViewNameProvider.FilterSettings.Actions.GetFilterDialog #>'
        type: '<#= EnvironmentStringProvider.HttpMethodPOST #>',
        dataType: '<#= EnvironmentStringProvider.DataTypeHTML #>'
        data: {},
        error: function() {
            DisplayMessage("<#= MessageStringProvider.ErrorMessages.GenerateFilterDialogFailed #>");
        }
});
```

Comment: @Whoever voted this question to be closed I advice to be more careful. This question has nothing to do with the one they provided as duplicate which is about T4 intellisense in general. Nothing to do with jQuery - probably never used T4 in the first place.

Comment: Robert, thanks for that clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short: Unfortunately not

There's no way (at least not that I'm aware of) of getting javascript intellisense into T4. It would have to be provided by means of an addon just like it is for c# code.

But there's a different question that bothers me: **What has jQuery code to do in a T4 template in the first place**? It's a design time template anyway and not runtime.

Comment: @Simon: You were doing this the wrong way. T4 is barely design time. What you want is for javascript files to execute at run time similar to ASPX files. This has to do with IIS configuration of HTTP handlers and processing of static *.js files that are now *executables*. That's how you should be doing it. But... **How did you do it in the end?**

Comment: We went along from using T4-Templates and ended up using string in javascript files. At the moment the best solution for us.